# How do I change the default sms font size? (ICS)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, fonts

I know I can change (in settings) whether or not the volume rocker can change font size, but is there a way I can change the default to be different? (I'd rather not have the volume button change function) I want the smallest size, but I can't seem to get it to stay that way

Answer (score 2):

The default appears to be simply what the phone itself is set to use as Font Size under Settings > (Device) Display. Change that to Tiny and your messages will display that way, but obviously everything else on the phone will also be impacted.